# kafka readStream with pyspark not able to connect

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am working with kafka topics and trying to create a readStream in my local machine with pyspark.

I have installed spark by home-brew By following command `brew install apache-spark`

I follow lot of tutorial but not able to get anywhere.

I also tried the Guid to Connect kafka with Spark -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html.

But this also does not help a lot.

Below is my code to connect pyspark with Confluent Kafka Topic

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("sparkkafka").config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "--xxx--:--xx--") \
    .option("subscribe", "NAME OF THE TOPIC") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .option("security.protocol", "some protocol") \
    .option("mechanisms", "PLAIN") \
    .option("[protocol]username", "XXX-username-XXX") \
    .option("[protocol]password", "---xxx--password----") \
    .option("schema.registry.url", "--- scheme registry url ---") \
    .option("basic.auth.credentials.source", "auth source") \
    .option("basic.auth.user.info", "info of user") \
    .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
print(df)
```

I tried both the way to execute this code.

1. `$: python3 fileName`
2. `$: pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0`

Both the things don't work.

The Error I am getting
[image: error after loading the script]

If anyone has already tried to connect with confluent-kafka and pyspark. With near realtime streaming can you please guide me some steps or some reference so that I can resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: homebrew install [latest apache-spark](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/apache-spark) so it's 3.1.2, so the package you should use is `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:3.1.2`.

Comment: @pltc thanks for you suggestion. I helped me a lot.

Comment: Spark-structured-streaming only reads bytes, by the way, so your Schema Registry properties are ignored, therefore "Confluent" is not the issue here

Answer (score 0):

Exception says org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.StreamWriteSupport class not found and this class is available from [spark 2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport.html). If you are using spark with version older than this then upgrade it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

homebrew install [latest apache-spark](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/apache-spark) so it's 3.1.2, so the package you should use is `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:3.1.2`